# Pandas: Flag overlapping dates but exclude certain rows if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a tough problem I just can't solve. I have a millions of rows where I need to flag overlapping dates between the current and previous row. The rows are grouped by 'KEY' and within this grouping I need to flag rows that have 'Date1' which overlaps with the 'Date2' of the previous row.

An overlapping row is where Date1 of the second row is less than Date2 of the previous row, AND Date1 of the second row is greater than or equal to Date1 of previous row.

Simply put: if date1 of the second row falls between date1 and date2 of the previous row, flag both rows as an overlapping row. FYI, on any given row Date1 will never be greater than Date2.

prev row date1 <= second row date1 < prev row date2

**The hard part that I can't figure out is that this step needs to be performed sequentially. That is if the second row in this grouping is flagged, then the next row (row 3) in this group will be compared to the first row (in this situation, the first row will also be flagged as overlapping along with row 2).**

Here is a dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['100000003', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009','100000034','100000034', '100000034'], 
              'Date1': [20120506, 20120506, 20120507,20120608,20120620,20120206,20120304,20120405],
              'Date2': [20120528, 20120610, 20120615,20120629,20120621,20120305,20120506,20120506]})
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"], format='%Y%m%d')
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date2"], format='%Y%m%d')
df.sort_values(by=['KEY','Date1','Date2'], inplace=True)
df[['KEY','Date1','Date2']]

    KEY         Date1       Date2
0   100000003   2012-05-06  2012-05-28
1   100000009   2012-05-06  2012-06-10
2   100000009   2012-05-07  2012-06-15
3   100000009   2012-06-08  2012-06-29
4   100000009   2012-06-20  2012-06-21
5   100000034   2012-02-06  2012-03-05
6   100000034   2012-03-04  2012-05-06
7   100000034   2012-04-05  2012-05-06
```

Since there are millions of rows and the size of each group varies, I wrote a for loop that will only iterate the max amount of groupby KEYs..

```
for item in range(df.groupby('KEY')['KEY'].count().max()):
    df['PrevDate1'] = df.groupby('KEY')['Date1'].shift(1)
    df['PrevDate2'] = df.groupby('KEY')['Date2'].shift(1)
    df['Overlapping_Hospitalizations'] = np.where(df['Date1'].between(df['PrevDate1'],df['PrevDate2']),'Y','N')
    print("DONE")
df
```

This works for each previous KEY, but ALSO I need it to compare to the initial KEY that caused an overlap for that grouping.

Expected Result:

```
    KEY         Date1       Date2       OverlappingFlag
0   100000003   2012-05-06  2012-05-28     N
1   100000009   2012-05-06  2012-06-10     Y
2   100000009   2012-05-07  2012-06-15     Y
3   100000009   2012-06-08  2012-06-29     Y
4   100000009   2012-06-20  2012-06-21     Y
5   100000034   2012-02-06  2012-03-05     Y
6   100000034   2012-03-04  2012-05-06     Y
7   100000034   2012-04-05  2012-05-06     Y
```

EDIT: Both the overlapping rows need to be flagged. See Expected Results.

Final Answer:

```
for item in range(df.groupby('KEY')['KEY'].count().max()):
    df['overlap'] = (((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift())   & \
                  (df['Date1'] >= df['Date1'].shift(1))  & \
                  (df['Date1'] < df['Date2'].shift(1)))  | \
                 ((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(-1))     & \
                  (df['Date1'].shift(-1) >= df['Date1']) & \
                  (df['Date1'].shift(-1) < df['Date2'])))
```

Comment: For your expected result, why is [4] N? 2012-06-20 is between 2012-06-08 and 2012-06-29? This might help get started on a vectorized approach: `df['overlap'] = (df.Date1 > df.Date1.shift()) & (df.Date1 < df.Date2.shift())`

Comment: Great catch! Interesting approach..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the expected result in the question does not fit the definition:

> The rows are grouped by 'KEY' and **within** this grouping I need to flag
>   rows that have 'Date1' which overlaps with the 'Date2' of the previous
>   row.

```
    KEY         Date1       Date2       OverlappingFlag
0   100000003   2012-05-06  2012-05-28     N
1   100000009   2012-05-06  2012-06-10     Y  # probably not
2   100000009   2012-05-07  2012-06-15     Y
3   100000009   2012-06-08  2012-06-29     Y
4   100000009   2012-06-20  2012-06-21     Y
5   100000034   2012-02-06  2012-03-05     Y  # probably not
6   100000034   2012-03-04  2012-05-06     Y
7   100000034   2012-04-05  2012-05-06     Y
```

An extension of @Evan's code for this case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['100000003', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009','100000034','100000034', '100000034'], 
              'Date1': [20120506, 20120506, 20120507,20120608,20120620,20120206,20120304,20120405],
              'Date2': [20120528, 20120610, 20120615,20120629,20120621,20120305,20120506,20120506]})
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"], format='%Y%m%d')
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date2"], format='%Y%m%d')
df.sort_values(by=['KEY','Date1','Date2'], inplace=True)
# if KEY is already an index, df = df.reset_index()
# df.set_index('KEY', inplace = True)

# this is really the only part changed
df['overlap'] = ((df.KEY == df.KEY.shift()) & \
    (df.Date1 < df.Date2.shift())) | \
    ((df.KEY == df.KEY.shift(-1)) & \  
    (df.Date2 < df.Date1.shift(-1)))

df.set_index('KEY', inplace = True)
```

Comment: This answer has the final piece that I needed. I updated the question stem with the final answer, which includes logic of keeping the first instance of an overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on your logic or how important KEY is; what about this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['100000003', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009','100000034','100000034', '100000034'], 
              'Date1': [20120506, 20120506, 20120507,20120608,20120620,20120206,20120304,20120405],
              'Date2': [20120528, 20120610, 20120615,20120629,20120621,20120305,20120506,20120506]})
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"], format='%Y%m%d')
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date2"], format='%Y%m%d')
df.sort_values(by=['KEY','Date1','Date2'], inplace=True)
df.set_index('KEY', inplace = True)

df['overlap'] = ((df.Date1 > df.Date1.shift()) & \
(df.Date1 < df.Date2.shift())) | \
((df.Date1 < df.Date1.shift(-1)) & \
(df.Date2 < df.Date2.shift(-1)))
```

Output:

```
               Date1      Date2  overlap
KEY                                     
100000003 2012-05-06 2012-05-28    False
100000009 2012-05-06 2012-06-10     True
100000009 2012-05-07 2012-06-15     True
100000009 2012-06-08 2012-06-29     True
100000009 2012-06-20 2012-06-21     True
100000034 2012-02-06 2012-03-05     True
100000034 2012-03-04 2012-05-06     True
100000034 2012-04-05 2012-05-06     True
```

Comment: this will generate false overlap if last  date1 of one key is less than first date1 of another. I think it's better to compare keys before `set_index`

Comment: Gotcha... how does one combine that sort of boolean test with a groupby statement?

Comment: added an answer, since it is too long for a comment.